# StackExchange Family of sites errors on Chromium / TinyCore Linux

Tags: support, browser-support

The other sites in SE family (Tested Unix, SE, askubuntu, ELL) All show me a functioning bar at the top of the page, but the rest of the site is just the background image. Oddly enough, SO works, but is wider than my screen by a bit and I have to scroll a little sideways to see the whole page.

This is a recent install of TinyCore linux with Chromium Version 23.0.1271.64 for Tiny Core Linux (165188)

I'm going to try updating my Chromium and will report the results here.

**Edit**
I just realized that if I scroll sideways on the other sites, the content is there, so this is likely a CSS issue.

Comment: I'm finding TinyCore to be a little less user friendly than I'm willing to work with, so I'll be switching to a different distro. I'm leaving the question, for now, in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Probably because that browser (version) isn't supported.

Comment: That is an *ancient* version of Chromium.  I'm surprised the rest of the internet works at all with it.

Comment: @Makoto Just run  your internet in Backward Compatibility mode. Marquee and Blink will work. Internet Explorer is consistent across the board: still broken.